# selenium click not firing entire event - behavior is different than user interaction

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an icon on my web app. I am sending a Click then sleeping for a bit. The icon click opens a window. When a user clicks on that icon, the window is opened, some user controls are displayed and populated at the top of the page (filter selections) and a grid of data is displayed.

When the click is issued in my Selenium test (c# binding if that is convenient for examples or useful in anyway), the window is opened, the filter controls are displayed but not populated. No grid of data is displayed.

Only testing in IE at this time since our app only runs in IE.

The new window has javascript errors that we do not experience in regular user execution. The app developer I asked indicates that he has seen these errors in debugging but has never bothered to research them since they do not affect user experience.

Does anyone have any insight into the IE web driver implementation that might cause this or any thoughts on how to work around it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you switching your control to the newly opened window?

Comment: Hadn't gotten there yet. The newly opened window is not loading. Is there any reason to suspect that switching to that window would do something about the javascript errors? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: My suggestion is to use firefox webdriver once to see the behavior of your code.